# primefaces multiple file upload only updating tree table with first file uploaded

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a treetable with a multiple file upload component. If i upload 1 file, it correctly updates my treetable with that file.

If i try and upload multiple files at the same time (lets say file1 and file2), it only updates the tree table with file 1. If i then upload another file (file3), it then updates the tree table with file1, file2, and file3 so it seems to be an issue with updating.

Does anyone have any insight into this or know if it's a bug?

```
<h:form id="attachmentsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:treeTable value="#{contentEditorBacking.attachments}" var="node">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputLink value="#{node.link}" target="_blank" disabled="#{node.disabled}">
                <h:outputText value="#{node.displayName}"/>
            </h:outputLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Size</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.size}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Modified By</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{node.modifier}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
            <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteProperty" actionListener="#{contentEditorBacking.deleteAttachment}" 
                    rendered="#{node.canDelete}" update="attachmentsForm">
                    <f:attribute name="filename" value="#{node.displayName}" />
                </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{contentEditorBacking.handleFileUpload}"
        mode="advanced" sizeLimit="#{contentEditorBacking.fileSizeLimit}"
        invalidSizeMessage="#{contentEditorBacking.fileSizeMessage}"
        allowTypes="#{contentEditorBacking.allowedFileTypes}" update=":controlTabs:attachmentsForm" />
</h:form>
```

Backer

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception{

        UploadedFile toSave = event.getFile();
        System.out.println("fileName = "+event.getFile());  
        String fileName = toSave.getFileName();
        String downloadLink = "";
        Long size = event.getFile().getSize();
        long version = 1;
        User user = cm.getUser();
        String creator = user.getUserName();
        Date modDate = new Date();
        boolean canDelete = true;
        boolean canUpdate = true;
        String displayName = fileName + "- pending";

        new DefaultTreeNode(new Attachment(downloadLink,size,version,creator,modDate,canDelete,canUpdate,displayName,true), attachRoot);
        addNeedToSaveMessage();
    }
```

**EDIT**

I added an id to the treeTable and changed my fileUpload update to the id of the treeTable rather than the id of the form tag and then solved my problem.

I always thought that by updating a parent element, it should update all of its children. Is that not true or are there exceptions to this as in the treeTable?

Comment: What is the UINamingContainer "controlTabs" you are referring to? Also  you do not have multiple="true" set on your fileUpload component

Comment: I don't need multiple set to true. You can choose a file, and then click choose a file again, and then you click upload and it uploads all the files. controlTabs is not needed apparently. I can just use `attachmentsForm`. doing it with controlTabs:attachmentsForm works too though.

Comment: I've edited the update statement to be just `attachmentsForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently for the file upload component, i had to update the actual tree table rather its parent form tag.